# Is there a easier way to update the newer version of a dll?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, upgrade

I have this situation

- MySolution

  - Libraries

    - SomeLibrary.2.0.1
  - MyProject1

    - Refer SomeLibrary.2.0.1
  - MyProject2

    - Refer SomeLibrary.2.0.1
  - MyProject3
  - MyProject4

    - Refer SomeLibrary.2.0.1

Now, I am updating the version of this library to 3.0.

One way to do it would be to update the dll in each of the project. Or I can write some script which will update the all project files to the newer version.

Is there any other way to mass update the dll in a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the references with the UseSpecificVersion set to true, it's enough to replace the library with the new one. After rebuilding the solution, your projects will reference the new library. This will work if the library name does not include the version number (i.e. your library is called SomeLibrary.dll)

If the library name is different, then a easy solution is to just open all *.csproj files in a text editor and perform a search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

When you doing refference to the SomeLibrary , you can added it from 
Project tab. But first you need that all projects will be under one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always add "lib" folder in a solution folder where I put all external libraries to reference. Then when I will update library in "lib" folder all references will be automatically updated.